# std::vector.erase() only erases half of what it should

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

I have a program where I have to delete some entries of a vector of structs. Im doing it like this

```
  for(int i=0; i<molec.size(); i++)
    {
      if(!molec[i].mine)
        molec.erase(molec.begin()+i);
    }
```

molec.mine is a boolean defined in the struct. The problem is that when I do this, it erases exactly half of the elements with molec.mine=false. I tried to search for some alternatives and found that I could do it with

```
vector.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(),vec.end(),1963),vec.end());
```

The thing with this is that I don't know how to do it with a vector of structs.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The code in the first example never looks at the element immediately following the one erased; in other words, it will never erase two elements that are next to each other.

Comment: So you know how when you erase an element, it moves the other ones? If `a[i]` is gonna be erased, it means `a[i+1]` **will become** `a[i]`, and `a[i+2]` will become `a[i+1]`. What does unconditionally incrementing `i` does then? I think you may benefit from reading ["How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Oh, I see. I understand now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for `std::remove_if`. As in

```
molec.erase(
  std::remove_if(
    molec.begin(), molec.end(),
    [](const auto& elem) { return !elem.mine; }),
  molec.end());
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`i++` shouldn't be performed when element is `erase`d. e.g.

```
for(int i=0; i<molec.size(); )
{
  if(!molec[i].mine)
    molec.erase(molec.begin()+i);
  else
    i++;
}
```

And yes, you should use algorithm library to avoid such issues.

```
molec.erase(std::remove_if(molec.begin(),molec.end(),[](const auto& v) { return !v.mine;}),molec.end());
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what i neeeded